# Ionic how make http get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework

How make request like this

[image]

I try to do it in provider, but have an error Response with status: 0  for URL: null

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let headers = new Headers();
      this.nativeStorage.getItem('token').then(
        data => {
          headers.append('auth', data['token'])
          this.http.get(apiUrl+page,{headers: headers})
          .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res)
            resolve(res.json);
          }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
        },
        error => console.error(error)
      );
    });
```

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: Do you able to hit api ? anything in console ?

Comment: it might be cross-origin-request issue, i just added [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) to chrome.(if you are using chrome)